# How to change geometry for one page without using \newgeometry or \restoregeometry

Tags: margins, geometry

I am trying to establish one geometry for my first page (not a title page), and use another for the rest of the document. However, because I am trying to make a template, and thus do not want to rely on a user to put in \newgeometry or \restoregeometry in the text of the document, I would like to establish these geometries in the preamble. Is there any way to do this?

**A minimum working example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lecturenotes}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\thispagestyle{plain}


\begin{lecture}{01}{Sample Lecture Notes}{John Sam}{01/01/2000}{Mark John}{PHYSICS 124: Physics of Energy}

\afterpage{\newgeometry{top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, outer=5.5cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.4cm, includeheadfoot}}


\end{lecture}
\theend
```

**The style 'lecturenotes'**

```
    \def\fileversion{1.0}
\def\filedate{2014/02/05}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, outer=5.5cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.4cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\handout}{
   \noindent
   \begin{center}
   \framebox{ \vbox{ \hbox to 13.5cm { {\bf {\course}} \hfill {Lecture \lecturenum\ -- \lecturedate} }
       \vspace{4mm}
       \hbox to 13.5cm { {\Large \hfill {\lecturetitle}  \hfill} }
       \vspace{2mm}
       \hbox to 13.5cm { {\it {Lecturer: \lecturer} \hfill {Notes by: \lecturescribe}} }
     }
   }
   \end{center}
   \vspace*{4mm}
}

\newenvironment{lecture}[6]{
    \begin{document}
    \global \def \lecturenum {#1}
    \global \def \lecturetitle {#2}
    \global \def \lecturescribe {#3}
    \global \def \lecturedate {#4}
    \global \def \lecturer {#5}
    \global \def \course {#6}
    \handout
}


\lhead{\lecturedate}
\chead{\lecturetitle}
\rhead{Lecture \lecturenum}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\newcommand{\theend}{\end{document}}
```

Comment: If *only* the first page is to have the altered layout and you don't want to require the user to do anything special, maybe a solution with the `afterpage` package is a possibility. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your layout with the manual geometry commands. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find a solution beginning from compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you are trying to keep everything under the hood, why not simply issue `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` under the hood as well?  There's also the package `changepage` (updated version of `chngpage`), which might work for your needs.  But the same basic 'problem' of keeping things hidden seems to be the same.  FYI: `etoolbox` offers lots of environment hooks, which might help keep things hidden.  An MWE would help clarify what might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @PaulGessler! Ill get onto a MWE, however in the case of afterpage - I have already tried using it, but issuing the command \afterpage{\newgeometry{}} after \begin{document} doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: You can't do like this: `\restoregeometry` has to issue a `\clearpage` command. A paragraph can't use two page geometries, because it's typeset before page breaks are considered.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the top margin on the first page, you're doing it the hard way.  Just use a negative `\vspace` to move the text up to wherever you want it.  The use of `handout` and `lecture` makes me wonder if this is not part of an even more elaborate set-up, but, in principle, you could do something like this:

```
\newlength\toplen  
\newlength\fplen   
\newlength\fpgap    
\setlength{\fplen}{0.5cm}  
\setlength{\toplen}{\dimexpr2cm + \fplen\relax}   
\setlength{\fpgap}{\dimexpr\fplen - \toplen - \headheight - \headsep - \topsep  
- \partopsep\relax}
```

Then plug `\toplen` into `geometry` and `\vspace*{\fpgap}` into your `\handout` command.  Note: this is really designed to give you only 0.5 cm between the top of the physical page and the top of the `framebox`.  Your original `geometry` command would leave significantly more space.

Here's a complete example, slightly changed from yours above.  (Mainly with respect to the not-advised hiding of `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`; but I also made `\lecture` [a command] from the environment `lecture`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{filecontents*}{lecturenotes.sty}
\def\fileversion{1.0}
\def\filedate{2014/02/05}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}

% Some lengths
\newlength\toplen
\newlength\fplen
\newlength\fpgap
\setlength{\fplen}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\toplen}{\dimexpr2cm + \fplen\relax}
\setlength{\fpgap}{\dimexpr\fplen - \toplen - \headheight - \headsep - \topsep - \partopsep\relax}

\RequirePackage[showframe, top=\toplen, %
bottom=2.5cm, outer=5.5cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded,
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.4cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\lecturedate}
\chead{\lecturetitle}
\rhead{Lecture \lecturenum}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\newcommand{\handout}{%
  \noindent
  \vspace*{\fpgap}%
  \begingroup
  \par
  \centering
  \framebox{ \vbox{ \hbox to 13.5cm { {\bf {\course}}
        \hfill {Lecture \lecturenum\ -- \lecturedate} }
      \vspace{4mm}
      \hbox to 13.5cm { {\Large \hfill {\lecturetitle}  \hfill} }
      \vspace{2mm}
      \hbox to 13.5cm { {\it {Lecturer: \lecturer} \hfill
          {Notes by: \lecturescribe}} }
    }
  }
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vspace*{4mm}%
  \par\ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand{\lecture}[6]{%
%   \begin{document}  <-- why ?
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \global \def \lecturenum {#1}
  \global \def \lecturetitle {#2}
  \global \def \lecturescribe {#3}
  \global \def \lecturedate {#4}
  \global \def \lecturer {#5}
  \global \def \course {#6}
  \handout
}


\newcommand{\theend}{\end{document}}% <-- why?
\end{filecontents*}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{lecturenotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lecture{01}{Sample Lecture Notes}{John Sam}{01/01/2000}{Mark
    John}{PHYSICS 124: Physics of Energy}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1-10]

\theend % <-- why?
\end{document}
```